# I have a visible disability. Should I tell my interviewer before going in?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, hiring-process, employment, disability

I have mild cerebral palsy. I can type, file, and so on. The main limitation I have is handwriting. This position also requires site visits, but I can't drive.
I know that some job responsibilities will be discussed, but should I mention it ahead of time?

Comment: We need more information. Location? A little bit more about the nature of the disability if you're comfortable sharing? Are there accommodations you're likely to need?

Comment: I have mild cerebral palsy. I can type, file, and so on. The main limitation I have is handwriting. This position also requires site visits, but I can't drive. @GlenPierce

Comment: Can you still do the job if they give you assistance?

Comment: If you can't drive, do you have another way to handle site visits?

Comment: Mostly likely uber. I'm willing to pay for it myself too. Don't know if I you address it out no where though @GlenPierce

Comment: How remote are the sites which you might have to visit? It sounds like Uber charges, paid out of your own pocket, might mount rapidly. Otoh, if drivers are given a mileage allowance, maybe you can get one too & set it towards your Uber costs.

Comment: You can get to most places using public transport.

Comment: @EdHeal, It sounds like you're in Europe. In the US, this is highly region-dependent. Bob Kobe, you really need to tell us where you're located. This is also important to know what legal protections you may have in place in your jurisdiction. In the US, we have the EEOC to protect you if you're applying to a company that has 15 employees or more.

Comment: Organizing transport by another method yourself when you are "expected" to drive could lead to practical and legal complications (getting Uber from unusual locations or at unusual times of day/night, insurance, taxation issues, etc). Discuss this in an objective manner in the interview. If the company requires you to do something as part of your job, you do it at *their* expense, not at your own.

Answer (score 4):

You can tell them reasonably safely once you got a appointment for an interview because at that point rejecting you without an interview would be a huge signal for illegal discrimination, so it won’t happen.

If you tell them in your application they can just throw your application away and there is little you can do.

PS. The interview is not worthless. Throwing away your application without ever seeing you is *prejudice*. In the interview you have the chance to overcome prejudice. And you encounter different “theys”. There may be a useless HR drone throwing away your application, where the interviewer would accept you. It’s not necessarily the company rejecting you, but different individuals.

Comment: Well, even after the interview they could throw OP's application for exactly the same reason without disclosing it, so why not spare a worthless interview ?

Comment: If this is in the US and if the employer has enough employees to fall under the EEOC, the OP would have strong legal protections. This is the reason why he should try going through the interview.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Can't they just say they have "more qualified" candidates?

Comment: They can say it, but they better be able to back it up with plenty of documentation in case the EEOC audits them, or in case someone sues them. It's also possible HR may nudge the hiring manager to hire the less qualified candidate if that candidate is in a protected class but can still do the job. Having good stats for an HR department is a good way to counter lawsuits (or counter the threat of lawsuits). That being said, one internship ages ago does not make me an expert in this domain. Also with Trump in office, it's very possible he defanged or weakened the EEOC as much as he could.

Comment: @bobkobe, You could try it both ways. You could send out resumes without that information and you could send out resumes to other companies with it. You could use two different google voice numbers in case you're afraid to lose track of what you said. I suspect that you'll get more callbacks with the resume not mentioning this information, but I can't actually be sure about that. For all I know, an HR specialist may want to get you interviewed you precisely because you're in a protected class. I don't know.

Comment: Can't see why Laurent's comment was voted up - because it lacks any logic.

Comment: @gnasher729 I typically disclose it on applications that  contain the ADA Sections. This company was someone I cold emailed though and I couldnt find a way to include my disability in my cover letter

Comment: @StephanBranczyk It's kind of causing nervousness not disclosing it prior. I appreciate your input though

Answer (score 2):

Most applications these days ask if an applicant needs reasonable accommodation. If you don't disclose your disability/need at this point, it could be considered dishonest.

If I had an applicant who did not disclose their needs up front and I found out later, I probably would not consider them for employment. *Not* because of their disability, but because I would feel that they hadn't been honest.

Many employers today try to accommodate the needs of employees as long as they are reasonable and it is not risking the health and/or safety of the employee. HR policies are very strict in this regard.

Unfortunately, even though it may be illegal, discrimination does still exist in some venues. I would simply encourage you to be confident in yourself and go after the jobs you are interested in. If a company doesn't want to hire you because of your disability, then you probably wouldn't want to work there anyway.

Comment: Actually no, it can't. If you told your HR department that, they would not be amused. When I worked in HR as an intern, my job was to scan thousands of resumes into a digital database. Anything that could be cause for discrimination under the EEOC would get blacked out (not by me, they didn't trust me to do that job, but by an HR expert). Granted, resumes with blacked out phrases most likely tipped off the hiring managers, but that's beside the point. Discrimination happens. And any step that could help reduce discrimination at the process level would be allowed and even encouraged by HR.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Fortunately I've not had that experience. I've worked for some rather large  companies and never have I received a resume with blacked out phrases. Generally resumes are work history and education. Most other things would be found in an application or cover letter.

Comment: @Cindy I honestly got this interview via cold emailing my resume and cover letter. I read it wasn't required to include it in, and with the structure of my letter, it seemed forced